# How to insert decimals. ex(12.5$) in Sqlite table

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using python and sqlite to create a storage management program and I've encountered a product that has the price of 12.5$. but the program doesn't accept the entry. The column that has this entry is assigned an INTEGER type. What type should it be changed to so it accepts float/decimal type.

When I tried to run it through the command line it gave me this error:

```
File "stores.pyw", line 1850, in submit
'Total_Buying_Pricev': 
get_value(Unit_Buying_Pricev)*get_value(Incomingvariable),
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Unit_Buying_Pricev is a textbox in tkinter. same is Incomingvariable.
The decimal is in the Unit_Buying_Price entry and I think this is the problem. the program doesn't accept the entry of this box and so it is considered none type or that's what I think.

the get_value function looks like this :

```
def get_value(Entry_widget):
    value = Entry_widget.get()
    try:
        return int(value)
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Note that this is going to be multiplied and summed so it can't be TEXT or DATE or BLOB for example.

Comment: *the program doesn't accept the entry* though SQLite would accept it.

Comment: I've added the error that prevents it from running. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Apparently the problem was in the `get_value()` function. Instead of `return int(value)` It should be turned to `return float(value)` and it was as simple as that.